# List of files after a date

Tags: bash

I want to get all files after a specific date. I tried with:

```
ls -ltr | awk {'print $6'} | sed s/-//g | awk {'if ($1-20110415 > 0 )  {print $1}'}
```

which works 50% fine. The last command prints only date of file. How to print date of file and filename? In the `awk $8` is the filename, but I don't know how to transfer till last `print` in the command line.

Thank you,
Luke

Comment: Do not use `ls` to parse files. Use `find`

Answer (score 25):

Try [find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) command like this:

```
find /my/path -mtime -1  # to get files modified in last 1 day

find /my/path -mtime -1.5  # to get files modified in last 1.5 day
```

Comment: (darwin)./ -mtime -1.5                                                                                               find: -mtime: -1.5: bad unit '.'

Comment: Yes find version on OSX is older that only supports integer number in `-mtime`

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a way to find updated files and process them, you could `touch` a file  after your process ends and use find's `-newer` :

```
-newer file
    File was modified more recently than file.
```

So when you need an updated files list, you'd want to do this:

`find /path/to/dir -newer touched.file`

This would recursively list all files in /path/to/dir that have a modification date that is later than that of *touched.file*. Don't forget to touch that *touched.file* again when you finish processing the updated files or make note of which file to test on your next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

`ls  -ltr --time-style=long-iso <path> | awk '$6 >= "2018-10-10" {print $6,$8}'`

This gives me all files on the specified path that have been modified on `2018-10-10` or later.

`--time-style=long-iso` is a good way of making sure the time includes the year, month and date. This helped me exclude old files if you keep multi year files.

Answer (score 0):

What about this slightly modified version ?

```
ls -ltr | awk {'print $6 " " $8 '} | sed s/-//g | awk {'if ($1-20110426 > 0 ) {print $1 " " $2}'}
```

Seems to do the trick for me... ?

Comment: Ops...sorry....I did not see you set date "26"....I set it back to 15....and works fine if filename does not include "-" symbol. Otherwise how can I do it? Thank you

Comment: The joy of extreme testing :)))

Comment: The only problem is some files have "-" in the filename and the sed command also changes the original filename.

Comment: Tweak the regexp to only modify the first 3 hyphens ! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) with one of its various time-based switches, then using the printf to specify what fields you wish to display?  You can find all the options in the man pages.

*EDIT* - I'm not on a suitable environment to give you an example right now - I'll try to update the answer tomorrow

Comment: ok. I saw atime takes only a number which is number of days. I also tried -newer "2011-04-15" but it returns error. I found this example

touch -t `date +%m%d0000` /tmp/$$
find /tmefndr/oravl01 -type f -newer /tmp/$$
rm /tmp/$$

but I am looking for another way without touch command

Comment: Yes, you could create a temp file, touch it with the required date and do the comparison with -newer...  I hadn't thought of that as a way to get the exact time you want.  However, the -daystart switch may be of use to you.  It effectively makes comparisons based on the actaul day in question (eg. newer than 12:45 pm on april 3rd 2010, would return all files newer than 00:00 on 4/3/10)  Might help you get what you need...

Answer (score 0):

I ran an experiment on my web server looking for files newer than a certain time.

```
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:47 -ls | wc -l
1214
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:47:30 -ls | wc -l
1177
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:47:40 -ls | wc -l
1087
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:47:50 -ls | wc -l
1016
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:48 -ls | wc -l
929
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49 -ls | wc -l
665
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:10 -ls | wc -l
665
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:12 -ls | wc -l
665
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:20 -ls | wc -l
634
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:21 -ls | wc -l
624
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:21.5 -ls | wc -l
616
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:21.6 -ls | wc -l
616
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:21.8 -ls | wc -l
612
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:21.9 -ls | wc -l
611
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt 2023-09-13T01:49:22 -ls | wc -l
610

$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-Sep-2023 1:49" | wc -l
665
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-sep-2023 1:49:21" | wc -l
624
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-sep-2023 1:49:21.6" | wc -l
616
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-sep-2023 1:49:21.7" | wc -l
614
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-sep-2023 1:49:21.75" | wc -l
613
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-sep-23 1:49:21.75" | wc -l
613
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "09/13/23 1:49:21.75" | wc -l
613
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "09/13/2023 1:49:21.75" | wc -l
613
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13/09/2023 1:49:21.75" | wc -l
find: I cannot figure out how to interpret ‘13/09/2023 1:49:21.75’ as a date or time
```

There might be other formats for time.